# Cutting the $d$-dimensional torus?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I am curious what the object you obtain is when you cut the $d$-dimensional flat torus $\mathbb{T}^d :=\left(\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}\right)^d$ along certain hyper-planes. Specifically, if you identify it with $[0,1)^d$ and consider a typical element $x=(x_1,\dots,x_d)$, I would like to cut it along the planes $x_i=x_j, i,j=1,\dots,d, i\neq j$. For $d=2$, one can check by hand that the resulting shape is isometric to $\mathbb{T}_{\sqrt{2}} \times  [0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}]$, where $\mathbb{T}_{\sqrt{2}}= \mathbb{R} /\sqrt{2}\mathbb{Z}$ is the appropriately scaled $1$-dimensional torus. Is there a general representation of what such a construction looks like in higher dimensions?

Edit: Just to clarify, I want to cut the torus along all such planes of which there are $d^2-d$ in dimension $d$. The final object (which will be a collection of manifolds of the same dimension $d$) may not be connected.

Comment: To clarify, are you asking, in effect: "Fix an integer $d \geq 2$ and distinct indices $i$ and $j$ with $1 \leq i, j \leq d$. What geometrically is the image of the hyperplane $x_{i} = x_{j}$ of $\mathbf{R}^{d}$ in the $d$-fold Cartesian product $(\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z})^{d}$, perhaps after identifying the torus with a $d$-fold Cartesian product of circles in $\mathbf{R}^{2d}$?"

Comment: No, not quite. I am interested in the shape obtained after \emph{cutting} the torus along all such hyperplanes $x_i=x_j$. So I first cut it along $x_1=x_2$, then say $x_2=x_4$ until I exhaust all such pairs. It is possible that the final object will not be connected (in fact in $d=3$ I am pretty certain it is not).

Comment: I see, thank you. <> What confuses me is, "cutting by hyperplanes" suggests intersecting an embedding with hyperplanes. On the other hand, the $x_j$ are intrinsic coordinates, not extrinsic coordinates. Particularly, $x_i = x_j$ is a relation in $d$-dimensional space, not (say) $2d$-dimensional space in which one usually thinks of the flat torus (a product of circles) as embedded. <> Separately, I'm now confused by which equations we're cutting by. If we exhaust all pairs $x_i = x_j$, we're effectively setting $x_1 = x_2 = \cdots = x_d$. But that seems not to be what's meant.

Comment: Regarding your first question, I am thinking of the torus essentially as a unit cube in $\mathbb{R}^d$ in which I identify opposite faces. In this setting the coordinates $x_1,x\dots,x_d$ can be made to agree with those of the ambient space (say by placing a corner of the cube at the origin). Regarding your second question, cutting is not the same as intersecting. If in $d=2$, and I cut along $x_1=x_2$ it does not mean that the resulting object satisfies $x_1=x_2$ at every point it just means that on its boundary it satisfies $x_1=x_2$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this helps but here are some pictures for the 4D case. The 4D torus I'm considering can be parameterized as
$$
(a, b, c) \mapsto \left\{
\begin{align*}
x &= (R_1 + (R_2 + R_3\cos\,a)\cos\,b)\cos\,c\\
y &= (R_1 + (R_2 + R_3\cos\,a)\cos\,b)\sin\,c\\
z &= (R_2 + R_3\cos\,a)\sin\,b\\
w &= R_3\sin\,a
\end{align*}\right.
$$
When slicing such a 4D torus in a hyperplane, we obtain shapes like this:
[image: Sliced torus]

Comment: Hmm... I've just tried with a $x_i=x_j$ hyperplane and the 3D slice I get is flat.